# TF400654 / TF400587 - TFS - Unable to configure Planning Tools / The following states does not exist

Tags: tfs, states

We did an upgrade from TFS 2013 to 2017.
When running the "Configure Features" wizard I get this error:

> [Error] TF400654: Unable to configure **Planning Tools**. The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'TaskBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Committed, Resolved, Rejected, Reopen, Approved.

here is my categories export for TASK:

```xml
<CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TaskCategory" name="Task Category">
<DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Task" />
<WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
</CATEGORY>
```

here is my processconfig export (i do have those states...)

```xml
<TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="500">
<AddPanel>
  <Fields>
    <Field refname="System.Title" />
  </Fields>
</AddPanel>
<Columns>
  <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
  <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
  <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
  <Column width="100" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
  <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
  <Column width="50" refname="System.ID" />
</Columns>
<States>
  <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
  <State type="Proposed" value="Committed" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Rejected" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Reopen" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Approved" />
  <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
</States>
</TaskBacklog>
```

I am clearly missing something but I don't know what... some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure those states exist in either of the work item types defined in your Task category, which are Task and Bug.

The TaskCategory is saying "work items that are or can be considered Tasks should have these states available". If the work items don't have those states, it's a problem.

The solution is to export your Task and Bug work items and look at the available states. If the required states don't exist, add them.

Comment: Hi, I did as you say and it solved my issue, thank you. I have transitions issue now (state xxxx cannot be reach from the Start transition) , those states are not relevant for Tasks so I can't use them in my workflow, do you know how can I get rid of the error about the transition?